# max and min values for a list with boolean and integer values

Tags: python, boolean, max, min

```
a=[0, True, False, 1]
a.sort() 
max(a)
min(a)
```

After sorting, the value of a becomes [0, False, True, 1]. On what basis, python sorts the original list like this when it is said that True is equal to 1 nd False is equal to 0.

- max(a) gives True as the result
- min(a) gives 0 as the result

How does Python treat boolean True as bigger than 1?
How does Python treat 0 as less than False?

Unable to comprehend how python compares boolean values with integers.

Comment: It does not treat them as lesser or bigger, it treats them as the same.

Answer (score 1):

> The built-in sorted() function is guaranteed to be stable. A sort is
> stable if it guarantees not to change the relative order of elements
> that compare equal

*python documentation.*

You get your result just because your list has equal values in this specific order.

Answer (score 0):

> How does Python treat boolean True as bigger than 1? How does Python treat 0 as lesser than False?

Python does not treat `True` as larger than 1. It just returns the first one if there are multiple maximal elements. Quote from
[the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> If multiple items are maximal, the function returns the first one encountered. This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools ...

The same goes for `min()`. `max()` returns `True` because it is equal to `1` and comes earlier in your input, not because somehow `True` is larger than `1`. This is evidenced by that if you switch `1` and `True` in `a`, you get `1` as `max(a)`.

---

> On what basis, python sorts the original list like this...

`list.sort()` in python is stable. `0` and `False` compare equal, but `0` comes before `False` in the original `a`, so after `a.sort()`, `0` is ordered before `False`. Same reasoning for why `True` comes before `1`.